# How to add java script to c# mvc in navbar

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, model-view-controller

How add following code as li element when user is log in? I try add li befor a element but it doesn't work.

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Logout</a>
```

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Project valuation", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                    {


                        using (Html.BeginForm("Logout", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
                        {
                            @*<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Logout</a>
                            <li onclick="location.href='javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()';"> Logout </li>*@
                            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()"><li>Logout</li></a>
                        }
                    }
                    @*<li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>*@
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your file, try to implement a script section as the following :

```
@section Scripts {
  <script type="text/javascript">   
      // Script goes here
  </script>
}
```

and in the `a` tag you can do something like this :

`<a href="#" onclick="yourFunction()" >Logout</a>`

Comment: Ok, but I want that it will be a <li> element that after click cause user logout